# Cantor-Lebesgue function is continuous. Proof explanation.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x$ be a real number in $[0,1]$ with the ternary expansion $<a_n>$. Let $N = \infty$ if none of the $a_n$ are 1, and otherwise let $N$ be the smallest value of $n$ such that $a_n = 1$. Let $b_n = \frac{a_n}{2}$ for $n <N$ and $b_N = 1.$ Show that the function $f$ defined by setting $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{b_n}{2^n}$$ is a continuous, monotone function on the interval $[0,1].$

**The suggestion is:** Pick $N$ such that $2^N > \frac{1}{\epsilon},$ and $\delta = \frac{1}{3^{N + 1}},$ and this should imply that whenever $|x - c|< \delta,$ then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon ,$ for $x,c$ having ternary expansions $(x_n)$ and $(c_n)$ such that $x_n = c_n$ for all $n \le N.$

*I tried to follow the suggestion and proving the statement for myself, but I had no idea what to do, and maybe this is reflected in the fact that it is not clear to me at all how is the $\delta = \frac{1}{3^{N + 1}}$ being used in the next proof.
I also need help figuring out why does the coloured equality holds.
Thanks a lot.*

**Proof:** Let $(y_n)$ and $d_n$ be the binary expansions of $f(x)$ and $f(c).$ Then, $y_n = d_n$ for all $n \le N$. Then

$$|f(x) - f(c)| = |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n}{2^n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{2^n}| = |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n - d_n}{2^n}| = |\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{y_n - d_n}{2^n} + \sum_{n=N + 1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n - d_n}{2^n}|$$
$$= \color{fuchsia}{|\sum_{n=N + 1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n - d_n}{2^n}| = \frac{1}{2^N}|\sum_{n=N + 1}^{\infty}\frac{y_{N+1+n} - d_{N+1+n}}{2^n}|} \le \frac{1}{2^N} < \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pink equality is wrong because they forgot to shift the lower bound of the sum. It should say

$$\left | \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{y_n-d_n}{2^n} \right | = \frac{1}{2^N} \left | \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y_{N+n}-d_{N+n}}{2^n} \right |.$$

Minor variations on this are possible, depending on how *exactly* you want to do it. In this version, the point is that what remains in the absolute value is less than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}=1$.

The idea here is very simple: if the first $N$ ternary digits of $x$ and $c$ agree then the first $N$ binary digits of $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ agree. Writing it up formally makes it a bit harder to see that.

Comment: ok, this way, the sum is clear to me. $1 = n + N = s$. So $\left | \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{y_n-d_n}{2^n} \right | = \frac{1}{2^N} \left | \sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{y_{s}-d_{s}}{2^n} \right |.$

Comment: Not true my first comment. I just had so multiply the $\frac{1}{2^N} $ and then shift the sum to get the right hand side...

Comment: The fact that I am counting from $n = N+1$ suggests this has something to do with the $\frac{1}{3^{N+1}}$?

Comment: @Trux See my last paragraph: $\delta=\frac{1}{3^{N+1}}$ means at least the first $N$ ternary digits of $x$ and $c$ are forced to agree.